# Error "A state mutation was detected between dispatches" in spite of modifying temporary object array and not the state

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects and for one scenario, I want to add a new object to the front of the array. The object array is fetched by an axios call and saved in redux state then passed down to the component as a prop.
Now in a scenario where a flag is true, I want to add an extra object to display as the first object in the array. So I created a temp array and made modifications there. Still it shows me error :

A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `list.notificationsList.0`. This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

The code is as follows

```
const viewNewReport = {"id":5,"name":"newRprt","description":"DESC"}

if (notification && !missingItemFound) {
    let tempNotificationsList = this.props.notificationsList
    tempNotificationsList.unshift(viewNewReport)
}
```

and I use tempNotificationsList to display on screen.
How can I avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use *Object Deconstruction*. In your case:

```
const { tempNotificationsList } = this.props;
```

Just like everytime you have to create a copy of a prop or state.

Comment: I am doing that. But still that editing gives me state mutation error.